# HmacSHA256 encoding in salesforce

Tags: crypto, encodingutil

I am trying to convert the following code from JAVA to Salesforce

**JAVA:**

```
        byte[] key =  BaseEncoding.base16().decode("wtv");

        SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);

        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);
        mac.init(signingKey);

        byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes(C_UTF8));


        return  BaseEncoding.base64().encode(rawHmac);
```

**Salesforce**

```
    private string calculateHMAC(string hmc, string signingString){

        Blob data = crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf(signingString), Blob.valueOf(hmc));

       return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(data);

}
```

My returning result is not the same, and I cant figure out why...

Is my conversion correct? What do you think I did wrong?

**Edit:**
Sample Data:

**HMC** = AED317ECD56FB9E4AE3CA43AC95E2F33FF0287404067E9811C920E60C99C064C

**singingString** =
currencyCode:merchantAccount:merchantReference:paymentAmount:sessionValidity:shipBeforeDate:shopperEmail:skinCode:CAD:AdyenTest:RA:199:2016-04-24T10:30:00Z:2016-04-24:a@a.com:FmDLArzH

**expected result**: C0j2GrWHFVq16AlF746Sk8c7QdyLDTn1hHslWV50D8A=

Comment: Do you have sample inputs and expected outputs that we could use for testing?

Comment: @DanielBallinger I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently I made a mistake in the conversion.

So here's the right conversion method.

The issue was that the HMC was a string representation of a HEX so I had to parse it down

Here's the correct method:

```
 private string calculateHMAC(string hmc, string signingString){
        Blob data = crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf(signingString), EncodingUtil.convertFromHex(hmc));
        return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(data);           
    }
```